Is this a scene from an existing old scifi movie? Numbered backpacks
So I've had this image of a scene from somewhere I've seen before in my mind for a few weeks now, trying to figure out if it's from some old scifi movie or not.
The only thing I remember is that there are several characters, humans, walking through some remote place. Something like a valley. Probably another planet. They have space suits on and backpacks, which are numbered.
So I tried googling it and found this:

Which looks very similar.
Is there a movie with such characters/items/scenes? Maybe from the 50s/60s/70s/80s?
I know Planet of the Apes has a similar intro, but those backpacks don't have numbers.
I'm starting to think my mind confused it with something else and made it up and it must've been the Apes, because what else? So, if it's bollocks, sorry.
I saw it on TV like 15-20 years ago btw. Probably a rerun.

Note, the image is for reference. The OP is not trying to ID the image, which would likely be off topic.

Besides Capricorn One, the only movies I'm thinking of are Mission to Mars (but backpacks are not numbered) or Red Planet (but I can't find reference of the actors seen from behind).
Any more precisions about the color of the valley? Was it like in the pic, or a more "alien" color? It could be helpful.

It looks like numbering space suits is becoming popular in movies and real life. Possibly because the suits are more likely to be taken off and stored during a mission while also being tailored to specific crew measurements.
The backpacks of the suits in The Martian were numbered. Here's an image of the prop for Matt Damon's character:

Image Source
This image is from Total Recall:

Image Source (Auto-play video on this page)
There is a real-life Mars Desert Research Station in Utah that apparently uses numbers on the backs of space suits:

Image Source
The suits in 2001: A Space Odyssey were not numbered. I looked for Europa Report stills but couldn't find one of the back of a space suit.

The pic in OPs question is actally also of the Mars Desert Research Station in Utah. It is taken from the 'interactive' documentary EXIT - (preview only).
